# Play/Scala: Map gets serialized as an array

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a KG class defined like so (case class and companion object):

```
case class KG(a: Resource,
              b: String,
              c: Option[Resource],
              d: Option[String],
              d: Option[Seq[String]])

object KG {
  implicit val writes: Writes[KG] = (o: KG) => Json.obj(
    "a" -> o.resource.getURI,
    "b" -> o.label,
    "c" -> o.subClassOf.map(_.getURI),
    "d" -> o.d
  )
}
```

This is the output of my sbt console when trying to figure out what was happening

```
test: KG = KG(http://some-url-this-is,test,Some(http://another-url-this-is),None,None)

scala> val ontology = Seq(test)
ontology: Seq[KG] = List(KG(http://some-url-this-is,test,Some(http://another-url-this-is),None,None))

scala> val initial = ontology.groupBy(_.c.map(_.getLocalName))
initial: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Option[String],Seq[KG]] = Map(Some(Person) -> List(KG(http://some-url-this-is,test,Some(http://another-url-this-is),None,None))

scala> initial.getClass
res8: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Option[String],Seq[KG]]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1

scala> Json.toJson(initial)
res7: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [["another-url-this-is",[{"a":"http://some-url-this-is","b":"test","c":"http://another-url-this-is","d":null}]]]
```

While `initial` is a Map, it is serialized as an array.... Why is this? Have I misconfigured any serialization implicits?

```
[
  [
    "another-url-this-is", 
    [
      {
        "d": null, 
        "b": "test", 
        "a": "http://some-url-this-is", 
        "c": "http://another-url-this-is"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the only `Writes[Map[_,_]]` Play JSON provides is for `Map[String, V]`, as those are guaranteed to be serializable as a JSON object.  For all other key types, the fact that a `Map[K,V]` is an `Iterable[(K, V)]` (if you have some experience with a Lisp, this is effectively like an "association list": a list of pairs) means that the default `Writes[Iterable[(K, V)]]` takes effect.  This serializes each `(K, V)` as a JSON array of length 2 with the first value being the `K` and the second the `V`; all of these JSON arrays are then values in an outer JSON array.

This behavior arises from the fact that while the values in a JSON object can be any JSON value, the keys must be strings.  In the particular case of `Option[String]`, this doesn't work since there is no JSON string that one could use to represent `None` that wouldn't collide with a `Some` containing that string.

Play-JSON 2.8 does introduce [`KeyWrites` typeclasses](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/214) to serialize a `K` to a `JsString`.  In the particular case of `Option[String]`, though, this may not be of much value as you'd still need to choose a string: if you can be sure that that string will *never* occur, you could have a `KeyWrites` that blows up with an exception if you try to serialize the colliding string.  On the `KeyReads` side, though, this might lead to some tricky bugs if you get a JSON payload with that string as a key.

Niko's solution for getting a `Map[String,V]` is excellent; this answer is going into more detail on the why.  You might (if using Play-JSON 2.8) also consider replacing the `Option[String]` with a more meaningful constrained type and then defining a `KeyWrites` for that type.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer since my response was more of an applied conjecture. Was just trying things out and one of them happened to work. This is a detailed explanation of why the map should be defined as a Map[String,T].

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why but the problem here is that the Map is of type `Map[Option[String],Seq[KG]]`. If the groupBy is configured in order to retrieve `String`s for keys - instead of `Option[String]`s - then the serialization is performed successfully and the Json object represents actually a map. So if the code changes to the following:

```
val theMap: Map[String, Seq[KG]] = ontology.groupBy(_.c match {
        case Some(someActualString) => someActualString.getLocalName
        case None => "SomethingEmpty"
      })
```

the resulting Json is the following:

```
{
  "someKey": [
    {
      "d": null, 
      "b": "person", 
      "a": "http://someURL", 
      "c": "http://someOtherURL"
    }
  ]
}
```